# WCF client to java service using mutual certificates for transport and message security

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, service

I am trying to create a WCF client APP that is consuming a JAVA WS that uses three certificates of which two of them aer for signing and encryption and one is for transport. There is a private key that is installed on the server and a public certificate file was exported from the JKS keystore file. I have installed the public key and keys for signing and encryption into certificate store via MMC under Personal certificates.

Here is My Code from Form:

```
             public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol=SecurityProtocolType.Tls;       

                referencaServisa.obrtniWsServiceClient klijent = new referencaServisa.SomeServiceClient();


                var vs = klijent.Endpoint.Behaviors.Where((i) => i.GetType().Namespace.Contains("VisualStudio"));
                klijent.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove((System.ServiceModel.Description.IEndpointBehavior)vs.Single());

                klijent.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(@"https://213.147.119.174:4444/some-registar-ws/someWsService");

             CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();

             SecurityBindingElement sbe = SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateDuplexBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10);

                AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement asymetricElement=(AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)sbe;
                asymetricElement.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Rsa15;
                asymetricElement.ProtectTokens = true;
                asymetricElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;
                asymetricElement.SetKeyDerivation(false);
                asymetricElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
                asymetricElement.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;
                asymetricElement.KeyEntropyMode = SecurityKeyEntropyMode.ClientEntropy;
                asymetricElement.AllowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply=true;



                X509SecurityTokenParameters initiator = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToInitiator);

               /*X509SecurityTokenParameters recipient = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.RawDataKeyIdentifier, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToInitiator);
                asymetricElement.RecipientTokenParameters = recipient;
                asymetricElement.InitiatorTokenParameters = initiator;
                asymetricElement.InitiatorTokenParameters.RequireDerivedKeys = false;*/

                asymetricElement.MessageProtectionOrder = System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;
                asymetricElement.LocalClientSettings.IdentityVerifier = new MyIdentityVerifier();
                asymetricElement.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(
                 new X509SecurityTokenParameters());
                binding.Elements.Clear();
                binding.Elements.Add(asymetricElement);


                CustomTextMessageBindingElement customTextMessageBindingElement = new CustomTextMessageBindingElement("UTF-8", "text/xml", MessageVersion.Soap11);


                binding.Elements.Add(customTextMessageBindingElement);

                HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransportBindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement
                {

                    RequireClientCertificate=true
                };



                httpsTransportBindingElement.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
                httpsTransportBindingElement.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
                httpsTransportBindingElement.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
                httpsTransportBindingElement.KeepAliveEnabled=true;
                httpsTransportBindingElement.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;
                httpsTransportBindingElement.RequireClientCertificate = true;
                binding.Elements.Add(httpsTransportBindingElement);

                klijent.Endpoint.Binding = binding;


               referencaServisa.statusType status;
                string poruka;
                referencaServisa.registarskiUlozak[] registarskiUlosci;


          System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };



                // Begin using the client.
                try
                {
                   klijent.Open();
                    status = klijent.getUlosciByMbo("90445066",false, out poruka, out registarskiUlosci);

                    referencaServisa.ulozak receivedUlozak = null;
                    if (status.ToString() == "OK")
                    {
                        receivedUlozak = registarskiUlosci[0].aktivnoStanjeUloska.ulozak;

                        MessageBox.Show(receivedUlozak.vlasnici[0].redniBroj.ToString());
                    }


                    MessageBox.Show(status.ToString());

                    // Close the client.
                    klijent.Close();
                }
                catch (ProtocolException ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

            }


So I use three certificates one for signing one for encryption and one for SSL transport. I use custom binding for separation of certificates. When I start my app I get an error General security error:

The content type text/xml;charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=UTF-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 394 bytes of the response were: '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:InvalidSecurity</faultcode><faultstring>An error was discovered processing the &lt;wsse:Security> header (Unsupported key identification)</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'.

Here is my app.config :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="dasda12312.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="false"/>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="Remote.Disable" value="1"/>
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyClientCredentialsExtension">
          <MyClientCredentialsExtension>
          <clientCertificate findValue="removed" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" storeName="My" />
            <serviceCertificate>            
              <defaultCertificate findValue="removed" storeLocation="LocalMachine"  storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            </serviceCertificate>
            <transportCertificate findValue="removed" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"/>
          </MyClientCredentialsExtension>   
      </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>

     <customBinding>
      <binding name="cb">
        <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" requireDerivedKeys="true" includeTimestamp="true"
                  allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" securityHeaderLayout="Lax"
                  defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic256"
                  keyEntropyMode="ClientEntropy" requireSecurityContextCancellation="false"
          messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10" />
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
        <httpsTransport />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>

    <client>
      <!---->
      <endpoint address=""
        behaviorConfiguration="MyClientCredentialsExtension" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="cb"
         contract="referencaServisa.someWsService"
        name="SomeWsServiceImplPort">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="MyClientCredentialsExtension" type="SEOP.MyClientCredentialsExtensionElement,dasda12312"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <applicationSettings>
    <dasda12312.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="dasda12312_someReferenca2_someWsService" serializeAs="string">
        <value>https://213.147.119.174:4444/some-registar-ws/someWsService</value>
      </setting>
    </dasda12312.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>


Anyone had similar problem please help me and tell me how to fix this.

Thank you.
```